# Exchange 2019 Email Address Policy per user

Tags: exchange, email-server, outlook, android, exchange-2019

We have been tasked with changing our company domain for email.  Active Directory will remain the same.  I have created (but not applied) a new Email Address Policy that specifies the new domain.  The only other Email Address Policy is the default with our original domain.

When we migrate, I need to be able to apply it to users one-at-time, to assist them with updating their devices.  Google is failing me.  Does anyone out there have experience / tips on this process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create the new policy and don't apply it, as you already did.
- Turn off policy-based address management for all mailboxes:

  > Get-Mailbox | Set-Mailbox -EmailAddressPolicyEnabled $False
- When you want to apply the new policy to a mailbox, turn it on again:

  > Set-Mailbox -Identity name@domain.com -EmailAddressPolicyEnabled $True

GUI version:

[image]

Comment: That is exactly what we ended up doing.  Thank you!

Comment: Glad to have helped you. If so, please remember to upvote and accept.

Answer (score 1):

You could create rules to further define the recipients that this email address policy applies to, you can define an attribute for the user to which the new policy needs to be applied, such as company attributes, screenshot for your reference:
[image]

If you do it, the new policy only applied on users who has the specific attributes. Other users will not have any impact.